# Error when trying to read in from a text file. including InvocationTargetException, .RuntimeException and NumberFormatException

Tags: java, runtimeexception, numberformatexception, invocationtargetexception

Hi to print out values from values from a file but I am getting this error. Can anyone help point out the problem. I am using a pre made class for the exact format of the data from the file using toString. Therefore the problem is with the code I just provided and I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Please enter a shape file to open:
TwoRedCircles.txt
*

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:467)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:366)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:903)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.ReadShapeFile.createCircle(ReadShapeFile.java:32)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.ReadShapeFile.readDataFile(ReadShapeFile.java:60)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.ReadShapeFile.readDataFile(ReadShapeFile.java:82)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.BouncingShapesWindow.initShapes(BouncingShapesWindow.java:56)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.BouncingShapesWindow.<init>(BouncingShapesWindow.java:42)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.Main.start(Main.java:43)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:849)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.demo.Main
```

- 

> This is my code below.

```
package com.example.demo;


import javafx.scene.paint.Color; import java.io.*; import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadShapeFile {


private static Circle createCircle(String[] currentShape) {
    // <px> <py> <vx> <vy> <filled?> <diameter><r> <g> <b> <insertion time>
    int px = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[1]);
    int py = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[2]);
    int vx = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[3]);
    int vy = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[4]);
    boolean filled = false;
    if (currentShape[5].equals("true")) {
        filled = true;
    }
    int diameter = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[6]);
    int r = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[7]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[8]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[9]);
    Color color = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
    int insertionTime = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[10]);

    return new Circle(insertionTime, px, py, vx, vy, diameter, color, filled);
}


/**
 * Reads the data file used by the program and returns the constructed queue
 *
 * @param in the scanner of the file
 * @return the queue represented by the data file
 */
private static Queue<ClosedShape> readDataFile(Scanner in) {
    Queue<ClosedShape> shapeQueue = new Queue<ClosedShape>();

    //read in the shape files and place them on the Queue

    //Right now, returning an empty Queue.  You need to change this.

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] currentShape = in.nextLine().split(" ");

        if (currentShape[0].equals("circle")) {
            ClosedShape shape = createCircle(currentShape);
            shapeQueue.enqueue(shape);
            System.out.println(shape.toString());
        }
    }
    return shapeQueue;
}


/**
 * Method to read the file and return a queue of shapes from this file. The
 * program should handle the file not found exception here and shut down the
 * program gracefully.
 *
 * @param filename the name of the file
 * @return the queue of shapes from the file
 */
public static Queue<ClosedShape> readDataFile(String filename) {
    // HINT: You might want to open a file here.
    File newFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(newFile); //null is not sensible. Please change
        return ReadShapeFile.readDataFile(in);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("Could not find " + filename);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: One of your inputs is "true" and this is not a number, hence Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"

Comment: `at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.ReadShapeFile.createCircle(ReadShapeFile.java:32)` ← Which line of your code is line 32?

Comment: Line 32 is int diameter = Integer.parseInt(currentShape[6]);